# Using openpyxl is it possible to preserve the print area?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I use the following to write pandas dataframes to a preformatted excel template and then save with a different name:

```
def writer(self):
    '''
    Calls the excel writer function to create an object for writing out the
    report to excel. It loads an excel template, populates it and then
    saves the file. '''
    book = load_workbook(os.path.join(self.env.REPORT_TEMPLATE_PATH
                                      , self.env.REPORT_TEMPLATE))
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.filename()
                            , engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    return writer
```

Named Ranges are used to avoid broken links.

The issue I have is that the code when run outputs this:

```
\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\sitepackages\openpyxl\workbook\names\named_range.py:124: UserWarning: Discarded range with reserved name
warnings.warn("Discarded range with reserved name")
```

Everything seems to be fine in terms of the results but the print area is reset.
Is there a way to preserve the print area from the template in the new file?

Is there a way to see what is being discarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible in [openpyxl 2.4](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/print_settings.html). Until this is released you will have to manually recreate the print settings.

Comment: What is the timeline for release?  Is there a way to install 2.4 without hg on Windows?

Comment: openpyxl 2.4 will be released "when it's ready". I don't know of anyway to work with a checkout without Mercurial.

Comment: do you know how to fix?

`[Anaconda3] C:\ >pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl@2.4#egg=openpyxl

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): openpyxl from hg+https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl@2.4#egg=openpyxl in c:\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jdcal in c:\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): et-xmlfile in c:\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) `

Comment: No, there seems to be a problem with using this approach on unreleased versions. I think I need to file a bug with the PyPA team. You *might* be able to work with one of the zip files from Bitbucket but caveat developer as the has been difficult in the past. Download, unzip, and python `setup.py develop`

Comment: If I take the download package direct from Bitbucket Downloads what does that give me? https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/downloads

Comment: I've managed to clone the folder with command 
`hg clone https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl`
Is it possible to now install the 2.4 package?

Comment: Okay, now just `hg up 2.4 && pip install -e .` Further discussion would be better on the mailing list.

Comment: its done :-) now how do I set print area in python to excel equivalent of A1:O64,A68O97?

Comment: Is it also possible after the print area and headings are set for each sheet to export to PDF?